# Indian citizen, dropped out from college on student visa in Canada

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, canada, student-visas

So I dropped out from my grad school while in Canada, I'm an Indian citizen. My passport has student visa and Temporary Resident Visa of Canada.

1. I flew out of Canada and haven't entered back in India -- does this matter? Entering India again? (It's been about 5 months since I dropped)
2. I travelled to France, UAE and now I'll be flying back from UAE to Canada, and I hope on my tourist visa -- is that possible?

Just clarifying - my TRV is a completely separate Temporary Resident Visa on my passport I applied for before getting my student visa. I then got my student visa and entered canada as a student in November 2021. I'm okay with giving up/not using my Student visa at all. I only plan to stay for 3 weeks in Canada to visit my extended family there.

EDIT:

some important points:

1. TRV issue date: March 2018, Valid upto: November 2026
2. Student Visa issue date: September 2021, Valid upto: September 2023
3. Entered Canada for the first time, using my Student Visa: November 2021
4. Dropped from studies: April 2022
5. Exited Canada (for France): June 2022
6. Haven't been back to India (home country) yet
7. Currently in UAE
8. Planning to travel to Canada (from UAE): September 2022 -- on my TRV

Comment: When you dropped, have you informed IRCC accordingly? Not having done so might make a further entry way more difficult

Comment: For what purpose are you planning to return to Canada? You got the visa on the basis that you were a *student*.  Unless you have authorised leave, you generally don’t get to keep your study permit https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/study-canada/study-permit/prepare-arrival/study-permit-conditions.html I suspect if you try this it’s highly likely you’ll be denied entry on arrival

Comment: @Traveller They have a  *tourist* TRV, which should be different than their student visa, they want to make their entry on that TRV and not on that student visa

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Ok, sorry, I misunderstood the question. But I still think this is risky, the OP hasn’t been back to their country of residence since leaving Canada = no ties to home, and possibly a lot of ties to Canada from their student days.

Comment: In Canada a study visa is just a tourist visa plus a study permit. The OP is trying to reuse the visa they got on the basis of being a student.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella How do I have to inform the authorities?

Comment: @DJClayworth I have a Temporary Resident Visa, since before I got the Student Visa, is it still the same?

Comment: Yòur university can tell you how to inform immigration that you are no longer a student.

Answer (score 7):

**If you have a Multi Entry Canadian Temporary Residence Visa issued before you applied to be a student and still valid then you will probably be OK.**

This means you were considered a valid visitor even before you were a student, and (assuming you followed the rules while a student) should mean you are still approved. However it is possible that applying for a student visa and then not following through may adversely affect your eligibility. Immigration are able to refuse you entry even if you have a visa. You should be prepared to explain the reason for your dropping out of college. Also make sure that you informed immrgration of the fact you stopped being a student.

You should make sure of the usual things - having a clear plan and reason for your visit, a ticket out of Canada, some bank statements proving you have money, and documents indicating you have permission to enter the country you will be departing Canada for.

The rest of this answer covers the case where your visa was only to enter as a student.

*You were issued the Temporary Residence Visa  on the basis that you were a student. Now you are not a student - the purpose of the visa is no longer valid, and so nor is the visa
If you try to enter Canada you will be asked what the purpose of you visit is. (They will know you have dropped out of college so they know that's not the reason, and if you try to pretend it is you will be guilty of fraud.) If you have a really good reason for returning, and have a lot of documentation showing that you can afford to visit and have sufficient ties to your home country that you will unquestionably return then they may admit you. However the likelihood is they will not, despite the visa. Having failed to return to your home country decreases your chances.*

Note: Canadian student visas are Temporary Residence Visas, i.e. the same visa a tourist would have, plus a permit allowing them to study. So the OP was not granted a visa for tourism, they were granted one for study.

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed answer! 

Yes, I did receive my TRV completely separate for the purposes of tourism (I also have my sister living there, she's a citizen). I do have my Indian bank account statements that should prove my sufficiency. 

The only thing is, I haven't travelled back to my home country yet since I dropped. I'm an Indian citizen.

Comment: If I try to enter Canada now, let's say next month, and just enter on the basis of my completely separate TRV which is stamped on my Visa, would it be a problem?

My passport has the student visa and this tourist visa (TRV) stamped

Comment: @AngelaGilhotra What was the premise for your TRV and when did you get it compared to the date you dropped out? Do you have a compelling reason to leave Canada after visiting your sister (such as a job)?

Comment: I got it on the basis of tourism + sibling, it's a multi-entry 6 month TRV. I do have a job but it's a remote work, but I guess that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @Traveller I'll also have my return ticket booked (not to India, it's for another country, but will be exiting Canada for sure), fwiw

Comment: One thing to note -- I got my TRV _BEFORE_ I got my student visa; completely separate

Comment: @AngelaGilhotra Please edit all that information into the question. Also when does your non-student TRV expire? And how long before you applied for a study permit did you get the tourism TRV?

Comment: @DJClayworth just updated the question and added all the important information at the bottom! (very very grateful for all the comments and responses here)

Comment: @AngelaGilhotra Where are you planning on going after Canada? Is it a country where you have the *right* to enter (eg not tourist visa-dependent)? Did you have a visa to enter France?

Comment: @Traveller It's going to be tourist visa, yes. I'll be travelling to Mexico. For France I had a tourist Schengen visa

Comment: @AngelaGilhotra Ok, so not guaranteed entry to Mexico then. You should edit the info about your next destination into your question, including if you already have your visa for Mexico. Also, to answer your comment, remote work is not a tie. Are yoy effectively globe trotting as a digital nomad? Working remotely after entering as a tourist is still very often a complete no-no

Comment: @Traveller Since I have a schengen, mexican visa isn't required. I do have the entry permit for the country which is an additional requirement. 
I haven't been generating income in any of my visits, i was on leave from my work in most of them (i do have proof), and I stayed less than 30 days in the cities in all my visits

Comment: @Traveller "Working remotely after entering as a tourist is still very often a complete no-no": [not in Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/publications-manuals/operational-bulletins-manuals/temporary-residents/foreign-workers/what-is-work.html).

Answer (score 5):

> I flew out of Canada and haven't entered back in India -- does this matter? Entering India again? (It's been about 5 months since I dropped)

It matters. It shows that you have no real ties to India and no intentions of returning there.

> I travelled to France, UAE and now I'll be flying back from UAE to Canada, and I hope on my tourist visa -- is that possible?

To be permitted to enter any country as a visitor you have to show that you don't intend to overstay your welcome and go back home. You have shown so far exactly the opposite, and in the same country you're seeking admission to.

The visa in your passport is not a guarantee to enter, even if the visa itself is still valid. It's just an approval to approach. You may apply to enter. But you still need to satisfy conditions of admission, and as said before - the main one is that you can show that the visit is in fact temporary.

I don't believe you can show that.

Comment: migrated from expats

Comment: umm.. i _can_ show my temporary stay by booking return tickets?

Comment: @Ang maybe. But given what you've described here I would not be surprised if you're denied entry. To Canada or anywhere else where you don't have unrestricted right to be.

Comment: @Ang people who plan to stay permanently -- or at least longer than they're allowed -- sometimes book return tickets that they don't plan to use, and immigration officers are aware of this.  Return tickets have little value, and by themselves they have almost none.  They might be helpful as part of a comprehensive set of evidence, but the other evidence is likely to carry greater weight.  Relying solely on the return tickets is unlikely to succeed.  That said, not having entered India does not automatically disqualify you from returning to Canada.

Comment: +1 for "approval to approach."

Comment: I see. Thank you @phoog. I'll try & check what kind of proof would work best. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Ang it really depends on what you plan to do next and how you're paying for it.  In particular, it probably looks better if you show some concrete intention of settling somewhere at some point.  That could be as simple as sounding credible when the immigration officer asks you about your plans.  My experience entering Canada is not at all comparable to yours (I'm a US citizen; I've never held a visa, student or otherwise), so I have no sense of how much scrutiny you are likely to receive nor of how skeptical the officer is likely to be.

Comment: @phoog I seee - ok that's helpful! Thank you so much!